# Nginx reverse proxy and mosquitto docker containers

Tags: docker, mqtt, nginx-reverse-proxy

Is it possible to use [jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy/) to route mqtt messages to [eclipse-mosquitto](https://hub.docker.com/_/eclipse-mosquitto) containers?

So the clients can reach different brokers under different subdomains but under same port:

broker1.example.com on port 1883
broker2.example.com on port 1883

Comment: When establishing a standard TCP connection the domain name is used to lookup the associated IP address; it is not passed over the connection. As such I cannot see how the proxy could direct the traffic (pulling something from the MQTT `CONNECT` packet may work but that does not contain the domain). You could do this if you have multiple public IP's or use TLS ([SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No

As Brits says in the comments, you can not do hostname based proxying with native MQTT. Hostname based proxying only works with HTTP because the protocol explicitly includes the hostname in each request (the `Host` HTTP header), MQTT does not contain any information to identify the hostname the client is trying to connect to in the protocol.

It is possible to do it if using MQTT over TLS as the hostname is included in the TLS handshake so the server knows which certificate to present to the client. Detail of how to setup Nginx to use the TLS SNI header to proxy MQTT to different backends can be found on my blog [here](https://www.hardill.me.uk/wordpress/2020/10/14/hostname-based-proxying-with-mqtt/) and with Traefik [here](https://www.hardill.me.uk/wordpress/2020/10/17/more-mqtt-virtualhost-proxying/).

Both of those guides are for how to edit the settings file directly, not how to use it with the jwilder/nginx-proxy. It's been a while since I used that proxy config, but I don't think it supports automatically setting up TCP stream proxying as opposed to HTTP proxying.

Comment: Hello Hardillb, thank you for the answer. In case of using SNI, is it at client side required to do something more than just using TLS?

Comment: No, they shouldn't need to do anything special.

Comment: I have been trying to do it without success.. If i undertand correctly, i just need to user mqtt over tls? this mean generate certificates with server certificate with CN= broker1.example.com, modify mosquitto config file to use tls and listen on port 8883. At client side i have to connect using client certificates... but what about jwilder/nginx-proxy? nginx listen to port 80 i think but i need also to listen on port 8883 rigth?

Comment: No, re-read the blog post. In the example given, Nginx is doing the SSL termination not mosquitto. And No, you do not need to use client certificares. Also as I mentioned I said it probably would not work with the way jwilder/nginx-proxy is setup by default, you would need to pass it custom configuration files.

Comment: Hello Hardillb. make it any different if i use mqtt over websocket? The thing is that i want to use client and server certificates. I am able to reach my mqtt broker if i use the parameter "-p 9883:9883" in my docker run command... but i want that all my diferents brokers can be reached via the port 9883. I dont know how to get nginx to do the routing using clients and server certificates..

Comment: That's a different question to the one originally asked. MQTT over Websockets will probably work, but you will need to move to not doing the TLS termination in the reverse proxy, which makes things a little more complicated. Also it will depend what the clients are. Using Client certs with web browsers requires extensive setup on each client machine. You will do better to ask a new question.